# Not getting facebook permission screen in Android App. Using Facebook SDK 4.5

Tags: android, facebook

**I've been really stuck for several days with this one screen.**

[image]

When a user taps on "Login with Facebook", the app redirects to Facebook, authenticates if the user is not logged in to Facebook app, and returns a user email and some other details.

From then on, it never asks any permission. It just goes to Facebook and loads back with the data. But it never asks for the above screen. I need to have this screen so that the user knows what details the app is asking for. Can anyone help me out? I'm using Facebook SDK 4.5.

This is my first time using Android and Facebook SDK so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This screen will only come once if you are not log in with face book through this app so you have to call  LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();   so the login user may get logout from facebook and when you try again it will show that screen

Comment: That is how it is supposed to work, duh.

Comment: Sorry, But I don't get this screen not even once. If user is not logged in Facebook app, it asks to login, but never shows this permission screen.